# Displaying messages based on different combinations of radio buttons and check boxes

Tags: vb.net

I"m studying for my Visual Basics exam tomorrow and have kind of hit a wall on a practice program our prof gave us. It seems really simple, but I'm having some trouble.

The form has 2 group boxes, one titled Pet Preference and the other is called Preferences. In the Pet Preferences group box, there are 3 radio buttons (Hamburger, Hot Dog, and Hamburger and Hotdog). In the Preferences group box there are 2 check boxes (Mustard and Ketchup). There is also a button that when pressed displays a message box depending upon what combination of radio buttons and check boxes are selected.

If the Hotdog radio button and the Mustard check box are selected, a message that says "Mediocre" is to be displayed. If the Hamburger radio button and the Mustard check box are selected, a message that says "Excellent" is to appear. If any other combination of radio buttons and check boxes are selected, the message box is supposed to read "Medium Rare".

I apologize for not having any code to post, I have tried several different things and none of them have worked. I tried something like this

```
If radHotdog.Checked = True & chkMustard.Checked = True Then
   MessageBox.Show("Mediocre")
   If radHamburger.Checked = True & chkMustard.Checked = True Then
       MessageBox.Show("Excellent")
   End If
End If
```

But I think this one crashed and gave me an error saying something about the type True True not being able to be converted to Boolean, or something to that effect.

I also tried this.

```
If radHotdog.Checked = True Then
    If chkMustard.Checked = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Mediocre"
    ElseIf radHamburger.Checked = True Then
        If chkMustard.Checked = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Excellent")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Medium Rare")
        End If
    End If
End If
```

If I'm remembering correctly, this worked for the first combination, but not for any of the others.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You dont use `&` but `And`

Comment: Ah ok thanks, that fixed it. Except now I realize I'll need to write it in a way where if say Hamburger, Mustard, and Ketchup are all checked it'll give me the Medium Rare message rather than the "Excellent" one because Hamburger and Mustard were both checked. Is there a way to have it display the message if only the correct items are selected? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You are correct sir. I will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If radHotdog.Checked = True chkMustard.Checked = True And chkKetchap.Checked = False Then
    MessageBox.Show("Mediocre")
ElseIf radHamburger.Checked = True And chkMustard.Checked = True  And chkKetchap.Checked = False Then
   MessageBox.Show("Excellent")
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Medium Rare")
End If
```

valter

Comment: Ah ok thanks, that fixed it. Except now I realize I'll need to write it in a way where if say Hamburger, Mustard, and Ketchup are all checked it'll give me the Medium Rare message rather than the "Excellent" one because Hamburger and Mustard were both checked. Is there a way to have it display the message if only the correct items are selected? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @BethTanner *because Hamburger and Mustard were both checked* you mean `Ketchup and Mustard`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I tested it and when I click the button for Hamburger, and the check boxes for both Mustard and Ketchup, it gives me the "Excellent" message instead of the "Medium Rare" that it should be.

Comment: Thanks, actually the one before the edit works too. I tried it with every combination possible and got the correct message for everything. Thanks for the help!